# indentation: division in return line error correction

Tags: python, function, return

def my_func(input_pressure):
input_pressure = float(input("Enter pressure in psi: "))
return input_pressure/14.6
my_func(50)
print("Value outside function: %s",input_pressure)

Comment: Can you fix your indentation? Also, what is the error or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you edit your answer and fix the indentation? Check this out https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqwk.png

Comment: At line of return statement errors seems there.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: I have added my answer below. If that helps you, remember to leave an upvote and mark it as the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to fix your indentation error, your code should look something like this:

```py
def my_func(input_pressure): 
    input_pressure = float(input("Enter pressure in psi: ")) 
    return input_pressure/14.6 

my_func(50) 
print("Value outside function: %s", input_pressure)
```

However, your code will still not work due to a few issues which you need to note:

1. If you want to reuse the value of `my_func(50)`, you need to assign it to some variable first, e.g., `input_pressure = myfunc(50)`.
2. If you want to get the value of user input in the function to be reused outside of it, you need to return it as well, for example `return input_pressure, input_pressure/14.6`. Currently, `input_pressure` only exists within my_func, that is why you cannot access it outside.
3. If you want your user to provide an input within the function itself, you do not need to pass anything as the argument, i.e., `def my_func():` .
4. You need to fix your string formatting. Use `%` instead of `,`. I would link you to the docs, but I think [this tutorial](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting) will help you more.

So your revised code will be:

```py
def my_func(): 
    input_pressure = float(input("Enter pressure in psi: ")) 
    return input_pressure, input_pressure/14.6 

input_pressure, input_pressure_divided_14_6 = my_func()
print("Value outside function: %s" % input_pressure_divided_14_6)
```

Comment: print("Value outside function: %s", input_pressure/14.6){I have to add this line for conversion, Thanks a lot)